# wxPython sizer troubleshoot, How can I detach?

Tags: python, ide, wxpython, sizer

With a wxpython program, I ran into following situation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/a/source.py", line ###, in onChoice
    self.__do_layout(self.GetPosition()[0], self.GetPosition()[1], self.GetSize().GetWidth())
  File "/path/to/a/source.py", line ***, in __do_layout
    sizer_10.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion ""!m_containingSizer"" failed at ./src/common/wincmn.cpp(2488) in SetContainingSizer(): Adding a window already in a sizer, detach it first!
```

So far, I have checked

1. self.notebook_1 has not been added to other sizers (at line ***)
2. adding a line "sizer_10.Detach(self.notebook_1)" just before line *** does not help.
3. nothing has been added to sizer10 at line *** (pycharm says so)

I have no idea about line ###.

This program aborts when run within pycharm, while it does not abort when stand alone, (but buttons and others do not work correct.)

Can any experts give me some hints for next step?

regards

Comment: Without being able to see the source code, there is no way to know. Is it possible to 
 perform the layout routine, more than once? Thus it's coded once but happens twice, giving you the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I checked the execution steps, it chokes at first occurrence. (so probably, not coded once happens twice.) Entire code is complex and huge, I am trying to extract essential lines, but not yet.

Comment: Solved! Several items are modified at second time. I am not sure why it worked, but detaching them before modification worked. Modifications are done in other functions, so I modified sizer_10 to self.sizer_10 and detached its content in that function. –